# Simplifying TextChange Event Handler for Multiple TextBox controls

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I was just wondering if it's possible to simplify these codes? i have MULTIPLE textboxes with the same textchange event

```
    private void txtOvertimeHours_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtOvertimeHours.Text.Length <= 0 || 
            txtOvertimeHours.Text == null || 
            txtOvertimeHours.Text == "0.00" || 
            txtOvertimeHours.Text == "0" || 
            txtOvertimeHours.Text == "0.0")
        {
            txtOvertimeHours.Text = "0.00";
        }

    }

    private void txtAllowance_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtAllowance.Text.Length <= 0 ||
            txtAllowance.Text == null ||
            txtAllowance.Text == "0.00" ||
            txtAllowance.Text == "0" ||
            txtAllowance.Text == "0.0")
        {
            txtAllowance.Text = "0.00";
        }
    }
```

//and so on

Comment: Winforms, webforms, wpf, what?

Comment: winform sir @JohnSaunders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way. You can use the same event handler for multiple events:

```
private void ZeroOutTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = (TextBox) sender;

    if (txt.Text.Length <= 0 ||
        txt.Text == null ||
        txt.Text == "0.00" ||
        txt.Text == "0" ||
        txt.Text == "0.0")
    {
        txt.Text = "0.00";
    }
}
```

You could probably also simplify the conditional. I haven't tested the code below:

```
private void ZeroOutTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal result;
    TextBox txt = (TextBox) sender;

    if (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(txt.Text) ||
        (decimal.TryParse(txt.Text, out result) && result == 0M))
    {
        txt.Text = "0.00";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void txtOvertimeHours_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ZeroOutTextBox(txtOvertimeHours);
}

private void txtAllowance_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ZeroOutTextBox(txtAllowance);
}

private void ZeroOutTextBox(Textbox txt)
{
    if (txt.Text.Length <= 0 ||
        txt.Text == null ||
        txt.Text == "0.00" ||
        txt.Text == "0" ||
        txt.Text == "0.0")
    {
        txt.Text = "0.00";
    }
}
```

Comment: If all of the event handler methods are really identical, then @JohnSaunders answer is better.